# Upload Blob to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a blob in azure blob storage but getting a ECONNREFUSED error.

what should i do to establish a connection in the port.
When i tried to open this with Azure storage explorer it showed me the same error.

I have checked the python dependencies and the versions are latest.
OS= Ubuntu 18.04

My connection string is something like

```
"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=local;AccountKey=<KEY>;BlobEndpoint=http://<SYSTEM_IP>:11002/local;"
```

CODE-

```
blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=blob_conn_str, \
                        container_name=container_name, \
                        blob_name=blob_name)
                        
                blob.upload_blob(data)
                print("Uploaded to blob: %s" % blob_name)
                print("Processed message..\n\n")
```

LOGS-

```
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:Request method: 'PUT'
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:Request headers:
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:    'x-ms-blob-type': 'REDACTED'
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:    'Content-Length': '331350'
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:    'If-None-Match': '*'
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:    'Accept': 'application/xml'
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.6.9 (Linux-5.4.0-73-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic)'
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:    'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:    'x-ms-client-request-id': '1b3784d4-b7b9-11eb-887c-0c7a15549246'
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:    'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
INFO:azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy:A body is sent with the request
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (4): <SYSTEM IP>:11002
Unexpected error 
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 329, in thread_runner
    fps_app.eisSubscriber()
  File "main.py", line 272, in eisSubscriber
    upload_blob_content(blob_conn_str, blob3,blob_name_top)
  File "main.py", line 205, in upload_blob_content
    blob.upload_blob(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 83, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py", line 693, in upload_blob
    return upload_block_blob(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/storage/blob/_upload_helpers.py", line 105, in upload_block_blob
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/storage/blob/_generated/operations/_block_blob_operations.py", line 224, in upload
    pipeline_response = self._client._pipeline.run(request, stream=False, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 211, in run
    return first_node.send(pipeline_request)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_redirect.py", line 158, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/policies.py", line 515, in send
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/policies.py", line 489, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/policies.py", line 290, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 103, in send
    self._sender.send(request.http_request, **request.context.options),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/transport/_requests_basic.py", line 291, in send
    raise error
**azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fcdc1fd66a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused**
```

Comment: Your connection string seems incorrect. It should be something like `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=local;AccountKey=<KEY>;BlobEndpoint=http://account.blob.core.windows.net;` assuming you're connecting to a cloud storage account.

Comment: Is that you use Azurite?

Comment: Instead of connecting to a cloud storage account i would like to connect to a local account. that's why i gave the end point with system ip @GauravMantri

Comment: A similar configuration was successfully ran in a different setup even without running azurite. if i use the devstoreaccount1 with azurite running in the terminal i am able to upload the blob. if i change the account name to something else it's not uploading @JimXu

Comment: Are you connecting to local storage emulator? Please note that the account name for local storage emulator will have to be `devstoreaccount1`.

Comment: @ambhareshvenkatraman  as Gaurav said, if you use storage emulator(microsoft storage emulator or azurite), the storage account name must be `devstoreaccount1`.

Comment: is it possible to perform these tasks without using storage emulator to store locally?
Like defining our account, container and storing blob and opening them as a storage account in Storage explorer

Comment: @ambhareshvenkatraman Now we cannot do that. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json